# How to check if there are multiple values within your SQL window and see if they are different

Tags: sql

I have one tables like below with some sample data:

Main table

| center | document | documentitem | profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NL100 | 100 | 00010 | 5 |
| NL101 | 100 | 00010 | 10 |
| NL100 | 100 | 00010 | 0 |
| NL102 | 100 | 00010 | 5 |
| NL200 | 200 | 00010 | 1 |
| NL300 | 300 | 00010 | 6 |
| NL300 | 300 | 00010 | 7 |
| NL300 | 300 | 00010 | 4 |

I need to create a new column based on the following logic:
The new column should be called scenario and is made up out of 3 scenario's.

1. scenario 1: The document and documentitem columns keep only one
   record for center. If this is the case the value for Scenario should
   be set equal to the value of Center (e.g. for document + documentitem = 200 + 00010 where there is only one value for Center.) In this scenario NL200 should be returned as value.
2. scenario 2: The document and documentitem columns keep multiple values for Center, but they are all the same. (E.g. for Document + Documentitem = 300 + 00010 where there are three values for center but they are all the same.) In this scenario only one of the values should be kept (doesn't matter which one, can use any aggregate function really)
3. Scenario 3: this is the most tricky one. The document and documentitem column keep multiple values for Center, but they are not the same. The value that should be kept in the final table is based on the value for the Spend column. The profit should equal 0. So NL100 should be kept as final value.

The output table should look like this:

| center | document | documentitem | profit |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NL100 | 100 | 00010 | 0 |
| NL200 | 200 | 00010 | 1 |
| NL300 | 300 | 00010 | 4 |

Hope someone can guide me in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: Your expected result has no scenario column.

Answer (score 0):

Scenario 1. Use the `COUNT` function with `GROUP BY` and `HAVING` clauses to get the count of `center` values for the particular `document` and `documentitem` values and to filter rows by value of count equal to 1.

```
SELECT t.* 
FROM t
JOIN (
    SELECT
        document, 
        documentitem
    FROM t
    GROUP BY document, documentitem
    HAVING COUNT(center) = 1
) t2 ON t2.document = t.document 
        AND t2.documentitem = t.documentitem
```

Scenario 2. The difference with the scenario 1 is in conditions in `HAVING` clause. As it's said there should be multiple rows (e.g. `COUNT(center) > 1`) with the same `center` value (e.g. `COUNT(DISTINCT center) = 1`. Also the outer query uses the `MIN` aggragation function to get one of the values of `profit` and the required `GROUP BY` clause.

```
SELECT 
    t.center, 
    t.document, 
    t.documentitem, 
    MIN(t.profit) 
FROM t
JOIN (
    SELECT
        document, 
        documentitem
    FROM t
    GROUP BY document, documentitem
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT center) = 1 AND COUNT(center) > 1
) t2 ON t2.document = t.document 
        AND t2.documentitem = t.documentitem
GROUP BY t.center, t.document, t.documentitem
```

Scanario 3. The difference with scenario 1 is in `HAVING` clause condition. As it's said there should be multiple rows for the same `document`  and `documentitem` values but with different `center` values (e.g. `COUNT(DISTINCT center) > 1` and the row with `profit` equal to 0 should be returned (e.g. `t.profit = 0` in `ON` clause conditions of `JOIN`)

```
SELECT 
    t.center, 
    t.document, 
    t.documentitem, 
    t.profit 
FROM t
JOIN (
    SELECT
        document, 
        documentitem
    FROM t
    GROUP BY document, documentitem
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT center) > 1
) t2 ON t2.document = t.document 
        AND t2.documentitem = t.documentitem
        AND t.profit = 0
```

Finally use `UNION ALL` operator to get all of the queries results together

```
SELECT t.*, 'scenario 1' scenario
FROM t
JOIN (
    SELECT
        document, 
        documentitem
    FROM t
    GROUP BY document, documentitem
    HAVING COUNT(center) = 1
) t2 ON t2.document = t.document 
        AND t2.documentitem = t.documentitem
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    t.center, 
    t.document, 
    t.documentitem, 
    MIN(t.profit),
    'scenario 2'
FROM t
JOIN (
    SELECT
        document, 
        documentitem
    FROM t
    GROUP BY document, documentitem
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT center) = 1 AND COUNT(center) > 1
) t2 ON t2.document = t.document 
        AND t2.documentitem = t.documentitem
GROUP BY t.center, t.document, t.documentitem        
UNION ALL
SELECT 
    t.center, 
    t.document, 
    t.documentitem, 
    t.profit,
    'scenario 3'
FROM t
JOIN (
    SELECT
        document, 
        documentitem
    FROM t
    GROUP BY document, documentitem
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT center) > 1
) t2 ON t2.document = t.document 
        AND t2.documentitem = t.documentitem
        AND t.profit = 0
```

Output

| center | document | documentitem | profit | scenario |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| NL200 | 200 | 00010 | 1 | scenario 1 |
| NL300 | 300 | 00010 | 4 | scenario 2 |
| NL100 | 100 | 00010 | 0 | scenario 3 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=2d5630a0fcae15aed59851ca299ee8e8)*

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Select T.center, T.document, T.documentitem, T.profit,
       Case
        When D.mn=D.mx And D.cn=1 Then 'Scenario 1'
        When D.mn=D.mx And D.cn>1 Then 'Scenario 2'
        When D.mn<>D.mx And D.mnp=0 Then 'Scenario 3'
        When D.mn<> D.mx And D.mnp<>0 Then 'Undefined Scenario'
       End As Scenario
From
mytable T Join
(
  Select document, documentitem, COUNT(*) cn, MIN(center) mn, MAX(center) mx, MIN(profit) mnp
  From mytable
  Group By document, documentitem
) D
On T.document=D.document And 
T.documentitem=D.documentitem And 
T.profit=D.mnp
```

The idea is to find the `MIN, MAX and COUNT` for the 'center' value, and `MIN(profit)` grouped by 'document, documentitem'.

Scenario 1 occurs when `MIN = MAX and COUNT = 1`.

Scenario 2 occurs when `MIN = MAX and COUNT > 1`. (multiple center entries but with the same value).

Scenario 3 occurs when `MIN <> MAX and MIN(profit)= 0`.

Undefined Scenario occurs when `MIN <> MAX and MIN(profit) <> 0`.

See demo from [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=79c3507a705a9137f2055dabb804bab7).

Update, to remove scenario column:

```
Select T.center, T.document, T.documentitem, T.profit
From
mytable T Join
(
  Select document, documentitem, COUNT(*) cn, MIN(center) mn, MAX(center) mx, MIN(profit) mnp
  From mytable
  Group By document, documentitem
) D
On T.document=D.document And T.documentitem=D.documentitem And 
((D.mn = D.mx And T.profit =D.mnp) Or (D.mn <> D.mx And T.profit =0))
```

See [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cf1892857bfc1eb7ab35b7e943940307).

Comment: Hi Ahmed, the requirement is to keep the output table having 4 cols only. So the scenario column shouldn't be there.